# How does strcat() work in C++?

Tags: c++, strcat

I have a difficulty in understanding how strcat works.

```
char A[] = "H";
char B[] = "L";
char C[] = "12345678901234567890"; // 20 digits => 20 bytes
cout<< &A <<" "<< &B <<" "<< &C <<endl;
strcat(A,C);
cout<< &A <<" "<< &B <<" "<< &C <<endl;
```

Output is

```
0x7ffd98b99f80 0x7ffd98b99f90 0x7ffd98b99fa0
0x7ffd98b99f80 0x7ffd98b99f90 0x7ffd98b99fa0
```

According to my understanding, before running strcat, difference in A's location and B's location is 0x10. This means, they have 16 bytes of space in between. After strcat, A has 20 more characters which means it should occupy 20 bytes more. To accommodate these additional characters, I thought that either A or B is shifted to a new location. But neither happens. Where is A storing all its bytes now? How does strcpy work?

Comment: Your code is broken.  You're overwriting memory that you shouldn't.

Comment: [std::strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)

Comment: `strcat` is _physically incapable_ of changing `A` to point to a different address, since all you pass is the value of that variable.

Comment: @SLaks Variables never change their address, there is nothing you can do (except for causing undefined behaviour) which will make `&A` change

Comment: @M.M: No; you could make it a pointer. (and pass the address of the pointer)

Comment: @SLaks pointers cannot change their address either, `&A` cannot change. You might be thinking of changing the value stored in a pointer (which would be `A`, not `&A`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcat` does not allocate new memory for you, it is your job to make sure the destination buffer is big enough. It will simply append to the original string assuming it can.

This is clearly stated in every documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `strcat`, *you* are responsible for providing adequate space. If you neglect to do so (as in your example), you write into unreserved space, which is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you are lucky.

`strcat()` copies the contents of B to the end of A.

In your case, that appears to be exactly where B already exists. You are lucky that your implementation didn't fail on that alone.

`strcat()` will never (re)allocate memory for a string -- the memory must already exist and be sufficient for the additional string data. Otherwise you are overwriting *other objects* in memory -- which may cause disastrous results.